# Attemped updating ubuntu, got corrupted

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 14.10

I followed a tutorial (can't find it anymore, the history is on the ubuntu's part)
where you basically changed the update center to allow all version updates, then updated it. After about 10-15 mins of downloading the update, and a couple of confirmations it started installing. (Upgrading from 14.04 trusty to 14.10 utopic)

After a couple of minutes of installing (also the screen got locked once), the screen just shut down. Black. Being concerned about what is happening, I pressed Enter, then escape, then backspace and several things like that. I leaved it running for about 10 minutes, and thought to myself "maybe it shut down the system and didnt shut down the hardware or something" and just held down the shutdown button until the computer shut down.

Then, after starting the computer, the usual GRUB screen appeared, and I selected Ubuntu. (I am dual booting with Windows 8.1, which I'm using right now)

Black screen for a couple of seconds, then an error appeared, and some [ OK ] messages and then it was trying something and got stuck. I don't exactly remember what it wrote but I can get a picture of it with my phone if neccesary. And it just stayed like that, so I figured that I broke something...

Grub still shows Ubuntu and Advanced options for Ubuntu.

Didn't want to try entering the advanced options or the Ubuntu in case I break even more stuff.

I don't have any files that I need to restore over at Ubuntu, (I don't use it a lot, maybe it's shared, I don't really know), so removing it wouldn't be a problem, but I still want Ubuntu so maybe I can have a tutorial for removing Ubuntu and installing one of the newest versions?

EDIT: I will probably uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall it unless there is any other way...

**EDIT 2:** I can get the terminal by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, and after logging in and using `sudo service lightdm restart`, I got the login GUI active, but when I type the password it goes into black screen for half a second and then just asks for the password again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up reinstalling Ubuntu over the corrupted one.

Didn't have any data at that partition so I guess that's OK.